# Changing HTML Value depending on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a price list for my graphics design website.

Basically, I have a base price of $150 for a website design, and I want to create a module where users can check optional boxes, to add to the price. Eg:

Price Starts from $150, which is in a total at the bottom of the page. The user can check an option upgrade costing something, I'll use $20 for the example. Once the box is checked, the total at the bottom of the page rises to $170.

I work with programming quite a lot, but not much JavaScript. I've never done anything like this before, and wish for it to all be client-side. Where should I start?

**EDIT -**

Here's some HTML of the basic page I have. Upon checking the checkbox, it's value should be added to the value of what is in the text area.

http://pastie.org/private/avwkmaqztfqxma5lg6y8q

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help if you provide some or your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to do this is:

- Set your base price as a variable in JavaScript
- Call a function when a checkbox is checked or unchecked
- Add or subtract the value of the check box from the base price

I added two things to your example code. First, for each checkbox I added an onchange function we'll call update(). Second, I gave "Total" an id of total.

HTML:

```
Piecemaker - 
<input name="piecemaker" type="checkbox" value="20" onchange="update(this);">
<br>
Network Bar - 
<input name="netbar" type="checkbox" value="15" onchange="update(this);">
<br>
10 Tags - 
<input name="tags" type="checkbox" value="5" onchange="update(this);">
<br>
Shopping System - 
<input name="shop" type="checkbox" value="20" onchange="update(this);">
<br>
<br>
Total: <input id='total' name="total" type="text" value="$150" readonly>
```

The JavaScript is pretty straight forward. Set a base price (running_total), and either add or subtract the value of the checkbox from running_total.

JavaScript:

```
var running_total = 150;

function update(feature) {
    // Check
    if(feature.checked == true){
        // Add value to running_total
        running_total += parseInt(feature.value);
        document.getElementById('total').value = '$' + running_total;
    }
    // Uncheck
    if(feature.checked == false){
        // Subtract value from running_total
        running_total -= parseInt(feature.value);
        document.getElementById('total').value = '$' + running_total;
    }
}
```

Here's a link to a working example on jsfiddle.net:
http://jsfiddle.net/dnA7q/1/

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simpe problem (no offense). What I would do is put the price in the checkbox value

```
<input type=checkbox value=20 id=feature>
```

Then, when it is clicked, use this value to calculate the total:

```
document.gelElementById('feature').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('total') += this.value;
});
```

You'll have to do some minor string manipulation and use `parseInt`, but I'm sure you can figure this out.

Comment: This didn't really help :/

Comment: @LegacyP7 what are you stuck on?